# Agregar otro botton en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy empezando en `Flutter` y no me deja crear otro boton al costado del anterior, es decir uno mas para restar al estado, el método funciona, pero no puedo agregar otro botón, vengo de `React` ¿alguna recomendación?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _decrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Decrement',
        child: Icon(Icons.remove),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a Flutter. Lo que sucede es que **el Scaffold solo permite un argumento de tipo FloatingActionButton**, no dos. Pero ahora te explico como puedes lograr el resultado que andas buscando.

Si colocas el mouse encima del parámetro `FloatingActionButton` podrás notar que este es de tipo 'Widget', esto quiere decir que técnicamente podríamos utilizar cualquier Widget, por que:

> In Flutter, everything is a widget

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo esto encuesta podemos utilizar el widget `Column` el cual tiene un parámetro children, lo cual crea un arreglo vertical de children(widgets), entonces para tu caso el código quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            tag: 'increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15.0, //Esto es solo para dar cierto margen entre los FAB
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _decrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Decrement',
            tag: 'decrement'
            child: Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Es bueno mencionar que para cada uno de los FAB el parámetro `tag` debe ser único, para evitar problemas relacionados con el Hero animation.